# how to reuse same images for multi products

Tags: import, product-images, simple-product

I have a lot of the same simple products but with slight changes, so I use the same image for them all. and as many would know, in magento when you upload a product image you can't use it again for another, you have to re upload it again.  So it will produce a large number of duplicate images in the disk...

For example, I have 2 categories named C1 and C2. All products under C1 have same product images 1.jpg and 2.jpg.  And all products under C2 have same product images 3.jpg and 4.jpg. By the way, all the products are simple product.

Fed up of uploading the same product images over and over! Can some one help me? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here is one of ideas. http://www.pixelpaul.net/magento-share-images-on-more-products/ But I strongly recommend you do it via rewrite.